# How to check if my request - response is encoded?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, character-encoding

This might be an obvious question. But I haven't encountered this scenario before.
In my Spring MVC application, I have the following configuration in web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The data transfer between the browser and the server occurs via JSON using Jackson Mapper.
The request - response headers as in Firebug is below:

```
Response headers
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server          Apache
Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Does this mean that the request-response is properly encoded? 
Is looking at the headers the only way of determining the encoding used?

**UPDATE**

If as Polve mentions below, the settings affect only the interpretation as UTF-8, then what should I do encode my response in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CharacterEncodingFilter only sets the encoding you want the other side to interpret the response (or request) as.

The request does not says that you want UTF-8 via [Accept-Charset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), so the client can send whatever he wants, and your filter says that you will **interpret** it as utf-8, even if the client specified another encoding (*forceEncoding=true*).

So no, it does not mean that your request is properly *encoded*, it says that you should *interpret* what is coming as utf-8.

Comment: ok can you please tell me how to ensure that it is properly encoded?

Comment: You can't :-) If you speak to me in English, it is customary for me to answer in English, but nothing stops me from answering in Norwegian. But basically you should set content-type as you described, along with  Accept-Charset (and actually encoding the page in that encoding), and most clients should behave politely. This is also a good read on the subject: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php

Comment: The ultimate purpose of this filter is to always tell the client that you use utf-8, and always interpret the responses as utf-8. If you then set up your server with utf-8 as default and all your responses are encoded in utf-8 then you are pretty safe. E.g. if you extract byte-arrays from String.getBytes() you get default chareset. Use String.getBytes("UTF-8") to convert.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, I wanted to know whether how will I encode my response in Spring MVC application which uses Jackson for mapping to JSON. It turns out the default encoding in Jackson is UTF-8.

For those who want to know more about encoding, will recommend polve's answer above.